# reactjs inputs showing values in svg

Tags: reactjs, svg

I was demanded to do a test where I have two columns, one with inputs and another with an svg

the input column it's ok, and I know how to obtain values etc

my doubt in here is to show this values in the svg

can you give me a tip or a link where I can read more about it, it's the first time I've seen this

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a picture of a desired result?

Comment: the final svg must show the current values that I obtain in a previus form..values such us color I picked(the svg should turn in the same color more less,and I have an idea of how to do that using css and blend), url adress I typed(this I don t know, maybe "cutting a space into the svg and showing the data??!!") ,etc...

Answer (score 0):

what a surprise!!!

finally when I uploaded the svg to my reactjs project I saw that it contains a bunch of code inside...now I  know where to put all my input values from the form

kinda like this:

```
"><rect class="aa" width="21.244" height="4.641" rx="2.32" transform="translate(0 13.922)"/><rect class="aa" width="16.227" height="4.641" rx="2.32" transform="translate(5.009)"/><rect class="aa" width="12.754" height="4.641" rx="2.32" transform="translate(13.122 6.961)"/><rect class="aa" width="9.281" height="4.641" rx="2.32" transform="translate(0 6.961)"/><rect class="aa" width="9.281" height="4.641" rx="2.32" transform="translate(0 20.922)"/></g><g transform="translate(12.827)"><circle class="aa" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(0.173 205)"/><circle class="aa" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(0.173 169)"/><circle class="aa" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(0.173 133)"/><circle class="s" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(0.173 97)"/><circle class="aa" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(0.173 61)"/></g></g><g transform="translate(3737 716)"><g class="b"><rect class="af" width="589" height="56"/><rect class="ac" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="588" height="55"/></g><rect class="s" width="119" height="32" rx="16" transform="translate(409 12)"/><g transform="translate(235.443 19.562)"><path class="ab" d="M255.65,4329.04a1,1,0,0,1,.56,1.75l-3.67,3.18,1.1,4.73a1,1,0,0,1-1.49,1.08l-4.15-2.51-4.15,2.5a1,1,0,0,1-1.49-1.08l1.1-4.72-3.67-3.18a1,1,0,0,1,.57-1.75l4.83-.41,1.89-4.459a1,1,0,0,1,1.84,0l1.89,4.45,4.84.42Z" transform="translate(-239.443 -4323.562)"/></g><rect class="r" width="211" height="21" rx="10.
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

the above solution doesn' t really work because there is no way in which we can modify values inside svg,at least without suffering trying to parsing this amount of information...instead there is a site in which we can put the svg code, and then we obtain a component:--->https://react-svgr.com/playground/ ...the rest is history